# How can i make my iPhone application universal (iPhone - iPad) application?

Tags: iphone

I have my iPhone appliction, using same application i want to make it universal (iPhone / iPad). Is there any way to get success for the above mentioned task?

I want to do only using the previous MainWindow.XIB file & Custom ccode if neccessary.

I am totally unknown to this concept, this is totally new to me.

If possible then please suggest me the code / link to make the universal application.

Comment: There are many tutorials out there to make an app universal. Bother searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When building new project in Xcode 4.1 and above you can chose if you want iPhone application, iPad application or iPhone/iPad application.

Cheers.

Comment: I have already developed the iPhone application. Now i want to make it universal (iPhone-iPad). For that can you suggest me?

Comment: Hi, if i helped you you should press that "V" icon next to my answer stating my answer was right